# setTimout() in callback not working, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'd like to know why setimout(fun(),time) is not working here:

Context: This shows a message and Hides it, i'd like to make it wait 2 seconds, but if i do as following it wont hide (normally i do it without the setimeout()

```
function mostrar_msj(msj){
  $('#notificaciones').text(msj);
  $('#notificaciones').animate({
          top:$(window).scrollTop()+"px"
      },
      {
          queue: false,
          duration: 350
  });  
  $("#notificaciones").slideDown(1000, setTimeout('cerrar()',2000));
}

function cerrar(){
  $("#notificaciones").fadeOut(2000);
}
```

I'm just confused, here :?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you are probably better off using jQuery's `delay` in this case.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want the #notificaciones to fadeOut after they complete the slideDown, just use an anonymous function as the callback for slideDown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, easier is to use [**`delay()`**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$("#notificaciones").slideDown(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
```

Animation functions are automatically queued.

---

But to answer your actual question:

1. You are not setting the callback correctly. This

   ```
   $("#notificaciones").slideDown(1000, setTimeout('cerrar()',2000));
   ```

   will set **the return value** of `setTimeout` as callback for `slideDown`. A proper callback would be

   ```
   $("#notificaciones").slideDown(1000, function() {
       setTimeout('cerrar()',2000);
   });
   ```

   But this does not explain why the `cerrar` is not called as obviously `setTimout` *is* called. This brings us to the second point:
2. If you pass a string to `setTimeout`, then it is evaluated in global scope. If you have this piece of code inside the `ready` handler, then `cerrar` is **not** in global scope and thus not found by JavaScript.

   For this reason, passing strings is discouraged. You should pass a function reference instead:

   ```
   setTimeout(cerrar, 2000);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you didn't understand how to use callbacks. Here's the proper code:

```
function mostrar_msj(msj) {
    $('#notificaciones').text(msj);

    $('#notificaciones').animate({
        top: $(window).scrollTop() + "px"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 350
    });
    $("#notificaciones").slideDown(1000, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#notificaciones").fadeOut(2000);
        }, 2000)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#notificaciones").slideDown(1000, function() { setTimeout('cerrar()',2000) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a function call when you should just reference the function:

```
...setTimeout(cerrar,2000)
```

Comment: @Thief, no it's not.  However, it is discouraged for the same reasons as eval.

Comment: `.slideDown(1000, setTimeout('cerrar()',2000));` the return value of setTimeout is an integer (the timeout id), not a valid callback...

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `cerrar` as function pointer:

```
setTimeout(cerrar, 2000)
```

see: [JQuery, setTimeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495903/jquery-settimeout-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend not using setTimeout() if you are already using jQuery.  Here is another way you could accomplish the same goal in a cleaner more jQuery-like fashion:

```
function mostrar_msj(msj){
        $('#notificaciones').text(msj);
        $('#notificaciones').animate({top:$(window).scrollTop()+"px" },{queue: false, duration: 350});  
        $("#notificaciones").slideDown(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
}
```

The delay function takes the number of MS for the timeout as its argument, and will continue executing the queued/chained jQuery operations after the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it this way, using the `delay` method

```
function mostrar_msj(msj){
    $('#notificaciones')
        .text(msj)
        .animate({top:$(window).scrollTop()+"px" },{queue: false, duration: 350})  
        .slideDown(1000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000);
}
```