# Why is this javascript function not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, undefined

I have this javascript code:

```
$(function(){
  var currentCarouselItem = 1; //set carousel to first slide
  var runCarousel = 1;

  $(window).load(function(){    
    setTimeout('autoScroll()', 10000);
  });

  function autoScroll(num){
    if (runCarousel == 1) {
      $('.carouselItem.' + currentCarouselItem).animate({left: '975px'}, 'slow', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).attr('style','');
        var nextItem = currentCarouselItem + 1;
        if (nextItem == 7) {
            nextItem = 1;
        }
        $('.carouselItem.' + nextItem).animate({left: '110px'}, 'slow', function(){
          $(this).addClass('active');
        })
      })
    }   
  }
})
```

Whenever I run the site it throws a console error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: autoScroll is not defined`

Any idea why it thinks it is not defined?

Comment: Scope issue.. just put the function outside the `$(function()` and it will work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, setTimeout not working.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495903/jquery-settimeout-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout('autoScroll()', 10000);
```

Why put it in quotes?

```
setTimeout(autoScroll, 10000);
```

That's for starters.

Additionally, you have scoping issues here.

Comment: this is generally good practice, but won't change the behavior in this case

Answer (score 3):

I could try answering it for you, but I think this guy does a lot better job:

[JQuery, setTimeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495903/jquery-settimeout-not-working)

Comment: Can't +1 you enough for this.

Comment: That sounds like "close as dupe"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your `autoScroll` function is inside closure created by outermost `$(function(){})`.  Therefore eval (used to evaluate your string in `setTimeout`) can't find it, as it runs in a 'global' scope.

You can move the definition of `autoScroll` outside.

Also, as **jcolebrand** suggested, remove quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because when you pass in a string as the first argument for `setTimeout()` that javascript basically runs `eval()` from the global scope on that string. `autoScroll` lives within the scope of `$(function() { })` and therefore can't be "seen" from the global scope.

Try changing it to `setTimeout(autoScroll, 10000);`

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of problems with your code, but the reason that the `autoScroll` function is not defined is that it defined within the scope of your document ready function, but is executed via `eval` after the document ready has gone out of scope without the proper closure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.carouselItem.' + currentCarouselItem).animate({left: '975px'}, 'slow', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).attr('style','');
                var nextItem = currentCarouselItem + 1;
                if (nextItem == 7) {
                    nextItem = 1;
                }
                $('.carouselItem.' + nextItem).animate({left: '110px'}, 'slow', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('active');

                });
            });
```

For starters you need a semi colon at the end of functions like this,