# Can setInterval slow down browser performance drastically?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, jquery-masonry

I am using the popular jquery plugin Masonry to fit my columns nicely in my layout. I am using a setInterval to solve the exact same problem as BoltHead had here:  [JQuery, setTimeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495903/jquery-settimeout-not-working)

The solution is to use setTimeout to update the masonry plugin every second like this:

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(update, 500);
});

    function update() {
        var $container = $('#packages');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.mainPackage',
            columnWidth : 316,
            singleMode: true,
            gutterWidth: 15
          });
        });
    }
```

Is this a bad idea as far as browser performance? I would think that jquery running this rather hefty function every second would slow things down. Is this a bad practice? The reason I am doing this is because I am using .slideToggle to slidedown more content, thereby needed masonry to readjust the layout. Any thoughts on this solution?

Comment: Why don't you update only when new content is added?

Comment: as in, update when slideToggle is triggered?

Comment: Yes, trying to update every second without any change in the layout would just be using the CPU for nothing.

Comment: Hypothetically if it is a bad idea to do it every second presumably it's twice as bad to do it twice per second like your code does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

slideToggle receives callback as second argument, so update your plugin there, something like this:

```
slideToggle(time, function(){
    update(); // this is your "update" function from question example
});
```

and yes, it is a bad idea to do that update periodically for no reason.

Comment: yes, a callback on the slidetoggle is a much better solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, running something like this will slow the browser down. You may not notice it at first, but the longer the script is running the worse it will get. I really like @vucetica answer.

Answer (score 0):

This depends only on how many block the plugin needs to "masonrify". If you have something like 20-50 blocks, it will be no problem to run the update every 500ms. This is from my personal experience with a case exactly like yours.