# how to wait in jquery before submiting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code:

```
 $('#txndatetime_reload_uk').val(values[2]);
 $('#customerid_reload_uk').val(sanderEmail);
  setTimeout(6000); 
   // alert('ok');
 $( '#activate_form_uk').submit();
```

I want to wait before submit the form for 6 seconds.

But  `setTimeout(6000);` is not working.

What am I doing wrong in it?

Comment: [Documentation on window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) might help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, setTimeout not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495903/jquery-settimeout-not-working)

Comment: thanks @ZougenMoriver  For response.I got it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#activate_form_uk').submit()
}, 6000)
```

`setTimeout()` takes two arguments:

1. function to execute
2. amount of millisecond to wait before calling that function.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` runs asynchronously. So directly after it is called `$('#activate_form_uk').submit();` gets executed. You need to pass a callback to setTimeout which gets executed after the 6 seconds:

`setTimeout(function() { $( '#activate_form_uk').submit(); }, 6000);`

Answer (score 0):

Use like below,

```
 setTimeout(function(){$( '#activate_form_uk').submit()}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.delay()`

```
$('#activate_form_uk').delay(6000).submit()
```